# Creating an array from a MySQL database 

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Not really sure how to explain this, but:

Say I have $array and I need to do query a MySQL database to grab the value of one row, 'name', and then store the array key as that name, but then store the value as the count of how many of rows there are.

So we have $array['bob'] with a value of 100 bobs in the database, then another $array['john'] with a value of 20 bobs in the database. How could I quickly do this?

Comment: Are you using PHP's mysql_* functions, mysqli, or PDO? Or none of the above yet?

Comment: `$array['john'] with a value of 20 bobs` What does that mean?

Comment: @webbiedave - I'm assuming that he means 20 johns there. 120 bobs would be a lot of bob.

Comment: can you give us an idea of what your mysql table structure looks like?

Comment: Yeah, here's my query so far: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ipaddress), name FROM table GROUP BY name -- so I'm trying to count all records of 'name', with no duplicate ipaddresses attached and put it into an array with no duplicates of the filename, too.

Answer (score 2):

With a single query and a `group by` clause:

```
$query = "select name, count(*) from my_table group by name";
```

The specifics of pulling the data from the database I leave up to you, but assuming you wind up with a multidimensional array of rows, you can map the name to the frequency of that name with:

```
$frequency = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
    $frequency[$row[0]] = (int)$row[1];
```

Comment: I've been trying that but for some reason I keep getting thrown back invalid results. My query: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ipaddress), name FROM table GROUP BY name -- I get 1-2 results but that's just not right. :(

Comment: While also using: while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $array[$r['name']] = $r[0];

Comment: @Talasan: That's not the query he suggested.

Comment: @Talasan: The query in your comment does not do the same thing as meagar's query.

Comment: Yes it does. The difference is in our count and that's all. :-P

Comment: @Talasan Then it's not the same thing is it? If it returns different results how can you possible argue that it's the same query?

Answer (score 2):

using PDO, it would look like this:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, count(*) FROM names GROUP BY name");
$sth->execute();

/* Group values by the first column */
$array = $conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Result:

```
$array = array('bob'=>'100', 'john'=>'20');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SELECT name, count(name) as count FROM names GROUP BY name;
+------+-------+
| name | count |
+------+-------+
| bill |     6 |
| bob  |    11 |
| joe  |    13 |
+------+-------+
```

which could be done such as:

```
$array = Array('bob'=>0,'bill'=>0,'joe'=>0);
$sql = "SELECT    name, count(name) as count
        FROM      names
        WHERE     name IN ('".implode("','",array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_keys($array)))."')
        GROUP BY  name";
if ($result = mysql_query($sql)){
  while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
    $array[$row['name']] = $row['count'];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Which renders:

```
array(3) { 
  ["bob"]=> 
  string(2) "11"
  ["bill"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["joe"]=> 
  string(2) "13"
}
```